# How do i effectively compare an image with another image whose resolution is double of the original image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two sets of `3D` images (they come in form of `2D stacks`). `Image A` is  `10 micron`, with size: `1000 x 1024 x 1017`, while image B is `5 micron`, with size: `2004 x 2048 x 2036`. I like to make some computations on randomly chosen set of the `2D slices` of `A`, and then compare this to the same set of slices for `B`. However, since `B` has twice the number of slices for each slice of `A`, will it be sensible to compare two slices of `B` to each of `A`? If so, how do i determine exactly which of the two slices of `B` make up a slice of `A`?

While contemplating on this, i also thought of blowing up `A` by `2` using `imresize` function for each `2D slice` that i chose for the computation. Will it be okay to compare this new `B` with the `A`, considering that i have completely ignored what happens with the `z-coordinate`?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should resize the image `A` to the size of `B`, carefully choosing the interpolation scheme. Note that if they are genuinely 2D images, you can not just interpolate each 2D slice, you need to do it as a whole.

Comment: Thank you @Ander Biguri. I am thinkin of using `'nearest'` or `'linear'` as the interpolation scheme. For the 2nd part of your response, if i do the interpolation as a whole, that still leaves me with the dilemma of deciding which two slices of `B` make-up a slice of `A`. Any suggestions as to how i could handle this?. N/B: These are real images from micro-CT.

Comment: I work in micro-CT myself. Generally you do not only know the size in voxel, but also in real units (assuming here that they are from the same projections). Therefore you can now the real location of the centers of the voxels, and use those location for getting the "big" `A`. I suggest using linear interpolation

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much Ander.

Comment: Do you know the locations of each sample? What I mean is, can you assign a triplet (x,y,z) for the location of each sample in A as well as each sample in B? If so, then you want to resample A so that you have its values at the same locations as you do for B. As for the type of interpolation you use, that depends on how much accuracy you require and the nature of your data.

Comment: What are you comparing? You do computations on a slice of A, do you compare the result to similar computations on the equivalent slice of B, or are you outputting a slice that is supposed to be similar to a slice of B? In either case, you probably want to compare slices. You're not using 3D information in your computation, it might not make sense to compare to multiple slices in B.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As OP mentions this is microCT, I assume they have recosntructed the same "real world" area with different resolutions, and want to compare them. Therefore each pixel has a [xyz] real world location, thus OP should just interpolate to the locations in the big one. Slices won't work because in [xyz] they won't match. In fact, no pixel will match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned this is microCT, I am assuming that both images are different size resolution of the same object. This means that pixels have specific spatial location, not only value, therefore for this case, there are no pixels (assuming a pixel is a infinitesimally small dot in the center of the cube) that match in both images.

So, lets assume that in image A, the locations of the pixel centers are their indices (1,1,1), (1,1,2) etc. This means that the image starts (pixel boundaries) at "world value" `0.5`, and ends at `size(imgA)+0.5`

Now, first lets transform the desired pixel coordinates for interpolation to this range. `imgB` pixel centers are then in locations `(ind-0.5)*size(imgA)/size(imgB)+0.5`.

---

Example: Assume

```
size(imgA,1)=3; size(imgB,1)=4;
```

therefore the pixels in `imgA` are at `x` location `1:3`. The pixels on `imgB` are,  using the above formula, in `[0.8750    1.6250    2.3750    3.1250]`.
Note how the first pixel is `0.375` from `0.5` (our image border) and the next pixel is at `0.75` (double `0.375*2`).

We scaled a higher resolution image to the same "real world" coordinates.

---

Now to the real stuff.

We need to create the desired coordinates in the reference (`A`) image. For that, we do:

```
[y, x, z]=...
   ndgrid((1:size(imgB,1)-0.5)*size(imgA,1)/size(imgB,1)+0.5),...
          (1:size(imgB,2)-0.5)*size(imgA,2)/size(imgB,2)+0.5),...
          (1:size(imgB,3)-0.5)*size(imgA,3)/size(imgB,3)+0.5);
```

Now these 3 have the coordinates we want. **Caution! each of these are `size(imgB)` !!! You need to have the RAM `5*size(imgB)` in total to work with this.**

Now we can interpolate

```
imAinB=interp3(imgA,x,y,z,'linear'); % Or nearest
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ander. I would go with your prescription, however, I should have mentioned earlier that lack of adequate computer memory is the reason i was looking for a work-around (I tried doing similar stuff yesterday but got frustrated with computer memory). Otherwise, the resampling method would have done the trick suggested by @Anonsubmitter85. I could have done this with the processing software (Avizo).

Comment: In any case, another idea would be to extract a subvolume from the center of `'B'` using the coordinates of `'A'`. There is however a little issue with this: the `z-coord` of `'A'` being odd does not allow an accurate extraction in that direction (at least from the processing software that i use).

Comment: @User110 interesting. I'd suggest to open a new question about this with the new information, but looking for the most memory efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your function is imresize3. You can change one volume to the other's dimentions with:

```
B = imresize3(V,[numrows numcols numplanes])
```

You can also explore interpolation methods.

Comment: 1) it was Introduced in R2017a (important info) 2) In OPs case, this may not be a good situation, as the pixels have specific spatial locations